# NTFS hard disk repair utility in linux

Tags: ntfs, hard-drive, formatting

Is there a hard disk utility which can format(NTFS) &repair a [HDD](http://reviews.cnet.com/laptop-hard-drives/western-digital-passport-usb/4505-9997_7-32097183.html) which has lots of bad sectors like Norton Disk Doctor from Linux ?

Comment: Try remapping damaged sectors using this script:
https://techoverflow.net/blog/2015/01/07/fixing-bad-blocks-on-hdds-using-fixhdd.py/

Answer (score 2):

A few others here have already mentioned `ntfsprogs` and `mkntfs`.

Also in the `ntfsprogs` suite is a utility called `ntfsfix`. Although the man page emphasizes that it's not a Linux version of `chkdsk`, I have successfully used `ntfsfix` to bring a non-bootable WinXP root disk back to life.

A convenient place to find `ntfsprogs` (and many, many other diagnostic, repair, and rescue tools) is the CD- or USB-bootable [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/).

Comment: This actually helped me recover my defect NTFS file systems. I had accidentially overwritten the first 512 bytes of it. ntfsfix recovered the file system quickly and easily!

Answer (score 1):

A modern hard disk on which you can't read/write from/to certain sectors anymore has consumed all the spare replacement sectors it had available, so it can't be "repaired" really.  It's basically as good as dead.  Did you check the [S.M.A.R.T.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) status of the disk (with either `udisks` or `smartctl`)?

In any case, [`mkntfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/mkntfs.8.html) (`mkfs.ntfs` is a symlink to that) supposedly does a check for bad sectors by default, if you don't use any of the -f, --fast, -Q or --quick options.

Answer (score 0):

I use TestDisk(http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Answer (score 0):

The `ntfsprogs` package on linux has a disk formating utility called `mkfs.ntfs`. I don't know how well it handles detection and blocking of bad sectors, but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian, there is a package called scrounge-ntfs, which claim to be a data recovery program for NTFS filesystems. I have not tried it yet because I do not have any corrupted NTFS filesystem.

Anyway, it would be safer to make a disk image of the disk with bad sectors and recover your files from that disk image instead of directly from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you attach the (corrupt) hard disk to a virtual windows box then you can use windows' own chkdsk.exe on it, etc. ref: http://www.howtoforge.com/ntfs-disk-recovery